# Custom URL Launching

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to open a URL

https://domain.com

with my application without it going to safari?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use a UIWebView to embed a browser in your application. See the docs at: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, add a UIWebView to your project.